# Java method with Generic argument called from result of catch block

Tags: java, generics, exception, try-catch, catch-block

I've run into an unexpected issue involving Exception catching and Java generics in signatures. Without further ado, the code in question (explanation follows):

```
public class StackOverflowTest {

    private static class WrapperBuilder {
        public static <T> ResultWrapper of(final T result) {
            return new ResultWrapper<>(result);
        }

        public static ResultWrapper of(final RuntimeException exc) {
            return new ResultWrapper<>(exc);
        }
    }

    private static class ResultWrapper<T> {
        private final T result;
        private final RuntimeException exc;

        ResultWrapper(final T result) {
            this.result = result;
            this.exc = null;
        }

        ResultWrapper(final RuntimeException exc) {
            this.result = null;
            this.exc = exc;
        }

        public Boolean hasException() {
            return this.exc != null;
        }

        public T get() {
            if (hasException()) {
                throw exc;
            }
            return result;
        }

    }

    private static class WrapperTransformer {

        public ResultWrapper<Result> getResult(ResultWrapper originalWrappedResult) {
            if (originalWrappedResult.hasException()) {
                try {
                    originalWrappedResult.get();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return WrapperBuilder.of(e);
                }
            }
            return originalWrappedResult; // Transformation is a no-op, here
        }
    }

    private static class Result {}

    WrapperTransformer wrapper = new WrapperTransformer();


    @Test
    public void testBehaviour() {
        ResultWrapper wrappedResult = WrapperBuilder.of(new RuntimeException());
        final ResultWrapper<Result> result = wrapper.getResult(wrappedResult);
        assertTrue(result.hasException()); // fails!
    }

}
```

Leaving aside, for the moment, questions of bad style (I completely acknowledge that there *are* better ways to do do what I'm doing here!), this is a trimmed down and anonymised version of the following business logic:

- class `ResultWrapper` wraps the result of a call to a downstream service. It either contains the result of the call, or the resulting exception
- class `WrapperTransformer` is responsible for transforming the ResultWrapper in some way (though, here, the "transformation" is a no-op)

The test given above fails. From debugging, I have determined that this is because `WrapperBuilder.of(e)` is, in fact, calling the generic method (i.e. `of(final T result)`). That (sort of) makes sense, if generic arguments are "greedy" - a `RuntimeException` *is* a `T`, so that method is a sensible (though unintended) choice.

However, when the `DownstreamWrapper::getResult` method is changed to:

```
// i.e. explicitly catch RuntimeException, not Exception
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    return WrapperBuilder.of(e)
}
```

then the test fails - i.e. the `Exception` is identified as a `RuntimeException`, the non-generic `.of` method is called, and so the resulting `ResultWrapper` has a populated `exc`.

This is completely baffling to me. I believe that, even inside a `catch (Exception e)` clause, `e` retains its original type (and logging messages `System.out.println(e.getClass().getSimpleName()` suggest that is true) - so how can changing the "type" of the catch override the generic method signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method that is called is defined by the **static** type of the argument.

- In the case you catch an `Exception`, the static type is `Exception`,
  which is not a subclass of `RuntimeException`, so the generic
  `of(Object)` is called. (Recall that `T` is translated to `Object` in
  compilation).
- In the case you catch `RuntimeException`, the static type is `RuntimeException`, and since it does fit `of(RuntimeException)`, the more specific method is called.

Note that `e.getClass().getSimpleName()` is giving you the Dynamic type, and not the static one. The dynamic type is unknown during compilation, while which method is invoked is chosen during compile time.

Here is a simpler code that demonstrates the same issue:

```
public static void foo(Object o) { 
    System.out.println("foo(Object)");
}
public static void foo(Integer n) { 
    System.out.println("foo(Integer)");
}
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Number x = new Integer(5);
    foo(x);
    System.out.println(x.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

In here, the method `foo(Object)` is called, even though `x` is an `Integer`, because the static type of `x`, which is known in compile time, is `Number`, and is not a subclass of `Integer`.